# User asked a question less than a minute ago, but does not exist?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-users

I've never encountered this before - a user [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27964858/541091) which was not migrated from another site. I viewed it almost immediately after it was asked (within the first minute) and edited to format the code, but the user user has no profile and appears like a deleted account.

[image: Screenshot of nonexisting user]

What's going on with this user account? Is it possible the OP disappeared within seconds after posting?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the user disappeared. They self-deleted their account about 2 minutes after posting that question.

Strange, very strange, but it happens.

Comment: Weird, but okay then.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski _shrug_ no clue why, but I'll speculate they didn't want their name associated with the post or account.

Comment: That would be my guess as well.

Comment: So...instantly no hope of ever having an answer to that question accepted.  Something not quite right about that.

Comment: @J.. But wat is community user for then?

Comment: @nicael: that just cleans up stuff, it does not accept other people's questions. See [Who is the Community user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) for more information.